# sed: grab first instance of html tag

Tags: html, regex, bash, sed

I have an html file that uses the tag `<table>` multiple times throughout the script. I want to use sed to grab and print to console just the first instance that the `<table>` tag is used.

This is a snippet of the html that I am trying to parse. There are over 10 instances of the `<table>` tag.

My HTML:

```html
<table border="0" class="first">
  <tr class="a">
     <th>Tests</th>
     <th>Errors </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="b">
     <td>32</td>
     <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" class="second">
  <tr class="c">
     <th>Tests</th>
     <th>Errors </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="d">
     <td>32</td>
     <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the code I'm running

```
sed -n 's:.*<table\(.*\)</table>.*:\1:p' surefire-report.html
```

I want to be able to grab everything within the first `<table>` div. So output should be just this:

```html
<table border="0" class="first">
  <tr class="a">
     <th>Tests</th>
     <th>Errors </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="b">
     <td>32</td>
     <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you show us the expected output?

Comment: While regex is possible to use in this case, [it's still not a good idea in general for HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I don't recommend this: `grep -Poz '<table .*(\n.*)*</table>(\n)(?=<table)' file.html`

Comment: Please [edit] the question and update with the expected output instead of adding it in comments. The example input is not ideal because there is only a single complete `<table></table>` pair in there anyway.

Comment: @Cyrus Neither answer has worked.

Comment: @User123 I've updated the question with the output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it should work...

```
FILE=surefire-report.html

START=$(grep -n -m1  "<table" $FILE | cut -d ':' -f1)
END=$(grep -n -m1 "</table" $FILE | cut -d ':' -f1)

sed -n -e "$START,$END p" $FILE
```

Comment: Is this something that I enter in bash/terminal?

Comment: Yes. You can create a bash script with this or copy and past in bash terminal